# Given this parabola equation with GL_LINE_STRIP, I need parabola shaped cylinder with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP?

Tags: opengl, gl-triangle-strip

I have code that draws a parabola given two end points and a value for droop/sag to simulate a wire.  I'm currently using a GL_LINE_STRIP to draw it, but it's limited to pixel thicknesses, and I need world coordinate thickness.  So what I need to do is pass in a radius for thickness and draw a cylinder with it's height segments at each point on this parabola. In this coordinate system +Y is up.  Here's my code:

```
const double pPrecision = 50;
double wx1, wy1, wz1, wx2, wy2, wz2, wx3, wy3, wz3;
double wa = gWires[i].Sag;
WorldToLocal(gWires[i].Lat1, gWires[i].Lon1, (gWires[i].El1 * FtToMtrs), &wx1, &wy1, &wz1);
WorldToLocal(gWires[i].Lat2, gWires[i].Lon2, (gWires[i].El2 * FtToMtrs), &wx3, &wy3, &wz3);

double mXZ = (wz3-wz1)/(wx3-wx1);
double mXY = (wy3-wy1)/(wx3-wx1);

wx2 = wx1 + ((wx3 - wx1) / 2.0);
wy2 = (mXY * (wx2 - wx1) + wy1) - wa;
wz2 = (mXZ * (wx2 - wx1) + wz1);

double denom = (wx1 - wx2) * (wx1 - wx3) * (wx2 - wx3);
double A = (wx3 * (wy2 - wy1) + wx2 * (wy1 - wy3) + wx1 * (wy3 - wy2)) / denom;
double B = (wx3*wx3 * (wy1 - wy2) + wx2*wx2 * (wy3 - wy1) + wx1*wx1 * (wy2 - wy3)) / denom;
double C = (wx2 * wx3 * (wx2 - wx3) * wy1 + wx3 * wx1 * (wx3 - wx1) * wy2 + wx1 * wx2 * (wx1 - wx2) * wy3) / denom;

double px = wx1;

//glLineWidth(gWires[i].Thickness);

glColor4f(gWires[i].R, gWires[i].G, gWires[i].B, 1.0f);
glBegin( GL_LINE_STRIP );
    for ( int p = 0; p <= pPrecision; ++p) {
        double thisZ = (mXZ * (px - wx1) + wz1);
        double thisY = (A * (px*px)) + (B * px) + C;
        glVertex3f(px, thisY, thisZ);
        px = px + ((wx3 - wx1) / pPrecision);
    }
glEnd();
```

As you can see, I have a WorldToLocal that converts Lat/Long/El to local opengl coordinates...wx1, wy1, wz1 is one end point while wx3, wy3, wz3 is the other end point.

Assume a cylinder precision of say 6 vertices per segment...I'm thinking due to the GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP plot method, I'll need to add these parabola points to an array and use them precalculated because I'll need to know the current and next segment while plotting my cylinder segments right?  The cylinder does not need to be capped on the ends.

Comment: How thick do you want this cylinder to be, also in segments? It can be drawn with a thickness of "1", i.e., a front-view only; or any number higher than that for a double-sided flat plane or a triangular, square, or higher cross section.

Comment: I want to pass in a thickness as a radius. You can see the commented out line about line width... That will be used to calculate radius. The precision is how many line segments, I'll need a new variable for cylinder divisions, I'll start with 6.